# Gracenote (GNSDK): what are the rate limits after upgrading to Accelerator plan?

Tags: gracenote

What would be the rate limits for GNSDK after joining to the Accelerator Beta plan? (max number of calls per second per user, and max number of calls per day per user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Accelerator plan is for commercial use, we try to make the query limit flexible to meet your needs. Typically, the limit begins from several thousand calls per end user per day, and can adjust accordingly. Of course, Accelerator plan developers can notify us in advance to set a query limit that fit their use case.